# How to split a row into multiple smaller rows using windows command line?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, grep

I have a large set of data. I want to break it into 3 separate row.
For example :

Input

```
391 896 635 702 041 635 027 177 495
```

Output

```
391 896 635
702 041 635
027 177 495
```

Is there anyway to do it only with windows command line?
Expecting a grep command or some sort of 1 line or small batch file to do this without using excel or any external tool.

Comment: This is possible with a small batch script, but not reasonably a one liner. Is each tokens string length always 3 characters, or does it vary? - this will change the solution

Comment: The token length vary, but its different lines.

Comment: @HariKrishna, I formatted your exanple data as you had posted it. However, your question title suggests that it should not have been several words eath on different lines, but all on one line. I have therefore changed it to suit the title. If this is wrong please use the [Edit] facility to correct it.

Comment: @T3RR0R, see my one-liner solution [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77958217/778560)...

Comment: @Aacini splitting hairs, but two liner. I stated reasonably, as readability generally suffers when using concatenated code blocks

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how you can use a string length function to parse a given number of tokens from a variable when the length of the tokens varies / is unknown.

After each iteration of the loop, the strings definition is trimmed from the leading end by the length of the tokens +1 to account for trailing white space. Parsing ends when the lines definiton has been trimmed beyond its length - aka undefined.

```
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableExtensions

REM delayed expansion must not be enabled prior to Macro definition

(set ^"$\n=^^^
%= This creates an escaped Line Feed - DO NOT ALTER =%
)

REM $StrLen Source: https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10983&sid=5cf312ccf7fedfa3db0d88ff90cd17f1#p69418

set $strLen=for /F "tokens=2" %%E in ("!! D """) DO for %%# in (1 2) do if %%#==2 ( %$\n%
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%1 in ("!_!") do ( %$\n%
%=         *** copy content to temporary variable, the carets are for extended length, up to 8191chars =% %$\n%
    (set^^ _=!%%~2!) %$\n%
    if defined _ ( %$\n%
        set "_len=1" %$\n%
        for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do ( %$\n%
          if "!_:~%%P,1!" neq "" ( %$\n%
            set /a "_len+=%%P" %$\n%
            set "_=!_:~%%P!" %$\n%
          ) %$\n%
        ) %$\n%
    ) ELSE set "_len=0" %$\n%
    for %%V in (!_len!) do ( for %%E in (%%~E) DO endlocal ) ^& set "%%~1=%%V" %$\n%
  ) %$\n%
) else ( for %%E in (%%~E) DO setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion) ^& set _=,

Set "AddTo=!Random:~-%%i!"
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Generate an example input line

    Set "Line="

    For /l %%i in (1 1 48)Do (
        Set /a "TknLen=!Random! %%3 + 2"
        For /f "Delims=" %%i in ("!TknLen!")Do (
            If defined Line (
                Set "Line=!Line! %AddTo%"
            )Else Set "Line=%AddTo%"
    )   )

    Echo(!Line!
    Echo(

    For /l %%i in (1 1 1000)Do if defined Line (%= Cease processing if Line undefined =%
        For /f "Tokens=1,2,3" %%G in ("!Line!")Do (
            Set "Group=%%G %%H %%I"
            %$StrLen% Group.Len Group
            Set /a Group.Len+=1
            Echo(%%G %%H %%I

            REM Modify Line definition by token groups length. 
            For /f "Delims=" %%i in ("!Group.Len!")Do Set "Line=!Line:~%%i!"
    )   )

(
    Endlocal
    Endlocal
    Pause
)
```

Answer (score 1):

By utilising .NET RegEx via PowerShell, here's a 'one line' 'batch file' example:

```bash
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content -Path 'P:\athTo\YourFile.txt') -Replace \"((?:[^^\s]+\s){2}[^^\s]+)\s\",\"`$1`n\" | Set-Content -Path 'P:\athTo\YourFile.txt'"
```

Simply replace both instances of `P:\athTo\YourFile.txt` to suit your environment.

It should be noted that this is untested, it should work without issue with your sample content, but without knowing what your interpretation of "large set of data" means, it is impossible for me to provide any guarantee.

*As this is not a free code writing service, I will not be providing any explanation of how this may work, or be modifying it to suit any updated requirements.*

Answer (score 1):

This small Batch with one-liner command do what you want. Just change the `3` by the number of elements you want to appear in each line:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "input=391 896 635 702 041 635 027 177 495 "

set "i=0" & set "line= %input: =" & set /A i+=1 & (if !i! equ 3 echo !line:~1!& set "i=0" & set "line=") & set "line=!line! %"
```

Output:

```
391 896 635
702 041 635
027 177 495
```

If the number of elements in the line is not multiple of the number N (3 in this case), then the `line` variable will end with the rest of elements, so it is convenient to add this line at end:

```
if defined line echo %line%
```